# How to make action() accessible on my Controller, any idea?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

Some help needed?
I already going numb on this, on the controller, the action link is not being found (404), but the action "Other" works fine.
- basic theme
- inside a module
- url I am calling is /admin/banner-image/link
- namespace app\modules\admin\controllers

I am using krajee EditableColumn and grid here.

Please, any idea, what am I missing?

https://gist.github.com/moplin/0c43c38bf0b42d74a3a13a51e4356edf

```
class BannerImageController extends Controller
{
    public function actions()
    {

        return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::actions(), [
            'link' => [
                'class' => EditableColumnAction::className(),
                'modelClass' => CexBannerImg::className(),
                'outputValue' => function ($model, $attribute, $key, $index) {
                    return $model->$attribute;
                },
                'outputMessage' => function($model, $attribute, $key, $index) {
                    return '';
                },
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function actionOther()
    {
        return 'other';
    }
}
```

and the EditableColumn configuration en the grid.

```
            [
                'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
                'attribute' => 'route',
                'filter' => false,
                'editableOptions' => [
                    'header' => '¿Link?',
                    'size'=>'md',
                    'formOptions'=>['action' => ['banner-image/link']],
                    'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXT ,
                ],
                'format' => ['text'],
            ],
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to not explicitly define `public function actionLink()` as you have with `actionOther`?

Comment: @plamen-nikolov actually its because I am using the Kartik's EditableColumn (http://demos.krajee.com/grid#editable-column) and I need to extend EditableColumnAction. I need to make a Grids column editable.

Comment: You have not  public function actionLink()  so the 404 is correct

Comment: Maybe this is not working because of php7.1, because it actually works on another project running under 5.6?

Comment: @scaisEdge that won't make any difference if you don't set it public the action would still be accessible. until set `private` or `protected`

Comment: can you show your `editableClumn` setup where are you using the `editableOptions` ?

Comment: @muhammad-omer-aslam there. I ended rebuilding the controller to have an actionLink(). But I really would like to understand why is not working?
Do you thing it has to be with calling the clases like EditableColumnAction::className() and not EditableColumnAction::class ?? (thinking on php version differences)

Comment: yes i was about to ask you to change them once and check, replace the `className()` with `::class` since php 5.5 has deprecated `className()`

Comment: but the thing is that if it was some problem of autoloading the class EditableColumn it would have been a different error,

Comment: Leave changing the `classname()` add a trailing slash to the URL you are providing to `'formOptions'=>['action' => ['/banner-image/link']],` and check if it works or not. @moplin

Comment: @muhammad-omer-aslam Actually  already tried that with many combinations, specially and I hope this is not the problem, because the controller is inside a module so I already tried with `'action' => ['/banner-image/link'] `, `'action' => ['admin/banner-image/link']` and `'action' => ['/admin/banner-image/link']`. I also tried with xdebug to make it work, and making custom routes by hand to the controller.

Comment: wait you have a module with the name `admin` and inside that module, you have the controller setup for the EditableColumn ? give me a while let me replicate it at my end

Comment: i have replicated everything at my end even the module and controller and action names are same and every time I hit the save button it worked every single time, can you confirm a few things,**1)** if you try to access the controller action `admin/banner-image/link` via browser what error does it throw `404` or `400`. **2)** the grid view is also a part of the admin module? **3)** can you confirm that the code above is the exact copy paste from your files and there are no spaces in the column properties or actions method in `BannerImageController` **4)** Yii version currently using. @moplin

Comment: the only difference is i have tested it on `advance-app` and you are on `basic`

Comment: 1. Its plain 404 if it was 400 would be good because it should be only post.
2. Yes it is and it's also a Kartik's component.
3. Yes it is copy-paste
4. 2.0.14

Comment: the last one is `2.0.14.1` can you run `composer update` i am really out of ideas this is weird

Comment: Me to. Well I made it work re rebuilding the action, but I really would like to understand "Why". I could post the answer with the action, but that would not answer the question at the end.

Comment: yes it won't be the answer to the question, but I am still looking into it and I still cant find the reason only thing left is i replicate it in app-basic and then check